# Is my center div 100% fluid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar like below which has `260px` on left side and `260px` on right side.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               |    Center 100% fluid width                       |             
|  SITE LOGO    |------------------------------------------- ----- | Right      +
|               |                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

left fixed width —— middle fluid % —— right fixed width
```

Below is my `fiddle` for the same. Can anyone let me know on how can i make my `center div 100% fluid`. 
http://www.bootply.com/wY95zqw6jx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float Left for Leftbar, Float Right for Rightbar. Both should be INSIDE your center container. Then give center container padding left and padding right with value of the width of your sidebars. Also your center div should be box-sizing: border-box; - so you can add width:100%; + Padding.

JS Fiddle: www.jsfiddle.net/KGF35/

Comment: Can't we achive the same with bootstrap?